# Names are getting overlapped in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android App, I am trying to insert names in a column forcefully into database but In database only last name is showing i.e. `Myself` because names are overlapping. Actually My database portion is weak.

This is what I am doing in my Database Handler Class,

```
public void addPoliticianNames()
{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "I");
    values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "Me");
    values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "Myself");
    db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);
}
```

What to do for getting these names sequentially into the column (Here I have to insert names forcefully as I have mentioned above). So, Is there any method for this ? Is there any role of cursor in doing this job (like `movetonext` method or something like that) ?

Please help me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make one loop for inserting data into database. it will pick one by one value from array and put it into database.

Put this method in your database class

```
public void deleteTable()
{
    database.delete(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, null);
}

db.deleteTable(); // call it with this line for delete all records of your table
```

// for inserting data into table.

```
    String[] a = {"I","Me","MySelf"};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, a[i]);
        db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Names are repeating in column when running the code for next time.

Comment: then you have to delete all rows before inserting data. @Shiv

Comment: How ? Can I have Snippet ?

Comment: Can I delete only this `KEY_POLITICIANNAMES` column from the table ?

Comment: Can I delete only this `KEY_POLITICIANNAMES` column from the table because I have more columns and don`t  want to delete data from that columns?

Comment: No you can't do that. you have to update your both column. @Shiv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert three records, you have to use three insert calls.

For example:

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "I");
db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);

values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "Me");
db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);

values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, "Myself");
db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);
```

Comment: I have more names to add. So, what to do in this situation ?

Comment: Names are repeating in column when running the code for next time.

Answer (score 0):

`@Shiv change the column name for every value`

```
public void addPoliticianNames(String ss)

{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, ss);


}
```

ss contain value firts time "I",second time "me" like that

Comment: I want to add names in same column name. So, what can I do here ?

Comment: And what if i want to add more names. And I cant see your Edited Answer.

Comment: every time when u want to add name u need to call your method like my edited answer

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I dont want to insert names by user. I want to insert it by myself means programmatically.

Comment: @Shiv u can add at run time by paasing value in your method public void addPoliticianNames(String ss)

Comment: See Henry's Answer, I want like that